# Count letters in string

Tags: c++

Can someone help me.

for example I input
for x `RandomName` for y `and`
it needs to count each `y` letter in x word, and output should be.

```
a: 2
n: 1
d: 1
```

```
void counter(string x, string y)
{

    int signs[100];
    int amount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++)
    {

        signs[i] = y[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length(); j++)
        {
            if (x[i] == y[i])
            {
                amount++;
            }
        }
        cout << y[i] << ":" << amount << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in you code:

1. You always compare `x[i]` to `y[i]` ignoring the `j` index completely, which means you will never count a letter that is not in the same place in both strings.
2. You have a `signs` array you assign values to, but never use it. Also, it has the size 100, but for what?
3. You never reset the `amount` variable after the internal loop, which means it will not count letter individually.

You have the right idea - two loops, one iterates over all letters in `y` the other over all letters in `x`.

Fix the indexes in the comparison, reset the `amount` to 0 after you print it, and get rid of `signs`, and you code should work.

Comment: You're right, I made mistake in the comparison. it should've been ```x[j] == y[i]``` , and also I needed to reset the amount. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You incrise amount every time you find a lettre that match the input, but the amount is the same for every letter taken in parameters. To fix it just create an array of amount for every letter in parameters.

Comment: I dont really understand. How would this look?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define pass ((void)0)
std::string x = "RandomName";
std::string y = "and";
int maxSize = max(x.size(), y.size());
char* letterList = (char*)_alloca(maxSize);
int used = 0;
for (int l1 = 0; l1 < y.size(); l1++) {
    char letter = y.at(l1);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        if (letter == letterList[i]) {
            continue;//Do not know if that is the right spelling
        }
    }
    letterList[used] = letter;
    used++;
    for (int l2 = 0; l2 < x.size(); l2++) {
        if (letter == x.at(l2)) { count++; }
    }
    std::cout << letter << " = " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Should do what you want

Comment: Not the best method but it is quite simple